# Why the capturing lambda cannot be applied to the std::valarray?

Tags: c++, lambda, stl, valarray

What unqualifies capturing lambda from being passed to `apply` method of `std::valarray`?
consider following code:

```
int main()
{
    std::valarray<int> arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    auto arr1 = arr.apply([](int val) { return val * 2; }); // compiles
    int n = 3;
    auto arr2 = arr.apply([n](int val) { return val * n; }); //does not compile
    return 0;
}
```

Live on coliru http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f0407046699574fc

Tested on https://gcc.godbolt.org/
Neither GCC nor MSVC or CLang would compile the above code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is in the definition of [`std::valarray::apply`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/apply):

```
valarray<T> apply( T func(T) ) const;
valarray<T> apply( T func(const T&) ) const;
```

The type of `func` in both members is a **function type**. Which when used as the parameter type of another function decays to a function pointer. Those member functions do not accept general functors. Only pointers to regular functions.

Now, a capture-less lambda has an implicit conversion operator to a function pointer. So the first lambda is converted to a `int(*)(int)` which is an address of regular function that can execute the lambdas body.

But lambdas that capture state cannot be converted in such a manner, and as you can see, cannot be passed as an argument to `std::valarray::apply`.

Comment: any idea why it was done in the first place? maybe because it would render vectorization or parallelization optimizations not applicable on such `apply` implementation?

Comment: @kreuzerkrieg - `std::valarray` was conceived long before lambdas we introduced to the language for one. Also, I would imagine this is to encourage passing "pure" functions. In modern C++, this stands out, I know.

Comment: ummm... they added std::begin/end specializations for C++11 for valarrays, why not add the rest of the modern stuff... Well, I guess simply the valarray is not as widely used as the rest of STL containers.

Comment: @kreuzerkrieg - Probably. Someone has to write a proposal for this to be inducted into the standard. If there isn't much usage, it's unlikely someone will write it.

Comment: `std::ranges::for_each` can be used as an alternative, since they allow for capturing lambdas.